# PowerShell - Condensing a line property into into from the pipe

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell, and I have the following example code and output to illustrate my problem:

```
select-string "$env:appdata\..\Local\test\*.ini" -pattern "example_adjustment=" | select filename, line | sort-object -property line -Descending >> file.txt

Filename                                                                        Line                                                                           
--------                                                                        ----                                                                           
test1.ini                                                                       example_adjustment="4.2"                                                       
test4.ini                                                                       example_adjustment="11.0000000"                                                
test2.ini                                                                       example_adjustment="1.20"                                                      
test5.ini                                                                       example_adjustment="0.90"                                                      
test3.ini                                                                       example_adjustment="0.90"
```

I want to be able to modify the output so that the "Line" values appear as their numbers only and in float format for the purpose of the sort performing correctly. The end result is I'd be appending that information to a text file.

How would I go about modifying the Line property? I saw a post about regex, but I cannot edit directly from the pipe using regex it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot edit directly from the pipe using regex it seems.

You most certainly can! :-)

Use the `-replace` regex operator inside a calculated property:

```
... |Select filename,@{Name='Line';Expression={$_.Line -replace 'example_adjustment="([^"]*)"','$1'}}
```

Comment: That formatted the line perfectly, thank you! I did not know about the calculated property. Last inquiry though; the Line still appears as a string. Simple way to cast it to a float so it'll sort the numbers correctly?

Comment: Disregard. I figured out about casting. Thanks again for the regex bit!